# Item Sorter, with Multiple Items per Filter

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm making several bulk storage silos and although I am familiar with the traditional filter design, i am wondering if it can be adapted to support multiple items. For example, one silos is designated to hold stone and cobblestone; can one filter handle both of those items? What about 3 or more possible items in the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it out, and the easiest way would appear to be just filtering out each individual block and putting it into the same chest. The issue with using a single hopper is that it will deposit the first item, even if you want it to deposit the 2nd item. Hope this helps!